# How can I use a variable in a Jenkinsfile inside sshagent?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

There are many threads about similiar problems on stackoverflow but they couldn't help me with my specific case:

```
node{
  def USER = "user"
  def ADRESS= "adress"
  def ARGUMENT= "argument"

  stage('test'){
    sshagent(['123123']) {
      sh 'ssh ${USER}@${ADRESS} "command ${ARGUMENT} && command"'
    }
  }
}
```

In the console output ${USER} and ${ADRESS} will resolve to an empty string but ${ARGUMENT} will resolve to "argument". How do I have to format these placeholders that they work? I have tried everything I could find but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try    sh "ssh ${USER}@${ADRESS} \"command ${ARGUMENT} && command\""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NoamHelmer pointed out:

sh "ssh ${USER}@${ADRESS} \""command ${ARGUMENT} && command\""

works.